# How to convert a function to listOf without lamdas?

Tags: kotlin

There example of works code:

```
package cryptography
typealias taskFun = () -> Unit
var i: Int = 0

object tasks {
    val supportTaskTextList = listOf("hide", "show", "exit")
    val supportTaskFunList = listOf<taskFun>(fun() { println("hide $i");i++ }, fun() { println("show $i"); i++ } , fun() { println("Bye $i"); i++ })
    fun hide() {
        println("Hiding message in image.")
    }
    fun show() {
        println("Obtaining message from image.")
    }
    fun exit() {
        println("Bye!")
        kotlin.system.exitProcess(0)
    }
    fun getTask() {
        println("Task (${supportTaskTextList.joinToString(", ")}):")
        val i = readln()
        for (idx in supportTaskFunList.indices) 
        {
            if (supportTaskTextList[idx] == i) return supportTaskFunList[idx]()
        }
        println("Wrong task: $i")
    }
}

fun main() {
 while(true) {
    tasks.getTask()
 }
}
```

Is code is works. But i want to call my methods without lamda. When i tried to just use them by name i got  "main.kt:4:43: error: function invocation 'hide()' expected"

in: `val supportTaskFunList = listOf<taskFun> = listOf(hide, show, exit)`

Yet, i can to use it like:

```
package cryptography
typealias taskFun = () -> Unit
// var i: Int = 0

object tasks {
    val hide = fun() {
        println("Hiding message in image.")
    }
    val show = fun() {
        println("Obtaining message from image.")
    }
    val exit = fun() {
        println("Bye!")
        kotlin.system.exitProcess(0)
    }
    val supportTaskTextList = listOf("hide", "show", "exit")
    val supportTaskFunList = listOf<taskFun>(hide, show, exit)
    fun getTask() {
        println("Task (${supportTaskTextList.joinToString(", ")}):")
        val i = readln()
        for (idx in supportTaskFunList.indices) 
        {
            if (supportTaskTextList[idx] == i) return supportTaskFunList[idx]()
        }
        println("Wrong task: $i")
    }
}

fun main() {
 while(true) {
    tasks.getTask()
 }
}
```

May i use it without lamdas? Just, like as in C++ though pointers on methods? And why i can't use functions without lamdas here?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `listOf<taskFun>(::hide, ::show, ::exit)`? Your question as a whole doesn't make much sense. There are no lambdas in your code. `fun() { println("hide $i");i++ }` is an anonymous function. And the code you claim to "work" behaves differently from the second code you showed, so it is unclear what you actually want to do.

Comment: Yeah, it was helped me. But why i can't to use it without (reflection) '::'? 
Problem is solved. But i not understand why i can to use it without '::' (reflection), but i think it is not so matter.
Thanks.

Comment: `::` is the syntax for getting a function reference. It's not reflection. You can't do it without `::` because the language designers decided on this syntax. I personally much prefer it to the C# way (implicit function reference by using name alone), which I think is less readable since you can't spot the difference between an already-existing function reference and a function that you are getting the reference of.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to reference a function by name is not using a plain name, but the `::` syntax, for which you still need the name of hte object `task` I think. You could try just writing `::hide, ::show`... but I am not sure it resolves here.,

```kotlin
val supportTaskFunList = listOf(tasks::hide, tasks::show, tasks::exit)
```

Short mention: This is a function type. According to the documentation this is not a lambda (in Kotlin terminology) as it does not define a new function or use the lambda syntax, just references an existing function.

Comment: Isn't a [lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax) expression the specific syntax for writing a function literal? As I understand it, `::hide` is a [function reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#function-references), but not a lambda.

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation, lambda referes to the syntactical construct of defining an adhoc implementation by using '{', '}' etc. Everything else is just a 'function type' apparrently. Me, coming from Java, used the wrong terminology. I will adapt the answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. (You could also copy the links from my comment — then I can delete it.)